# Use of past tense or present tense with "to (not) understand"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect

I'm struggling to see which of the following sentences are grammatically correct ?

> She just understood what you haven't understood yet.
> She has just understood what you did not understand yet.
> She just understood what you have yet to understand.

As we speak, "She" has already understood, but not the other person mentioned. They will eventually. So, I'm not sure which sentence is most appropriate?

Comment: 'Just' is an added complication here. 'She just understood the passage' defaults in meaning, at least to many Brits, to 'Understanding the passage came naturally to her' while 'She has just understood the passage' defaults to the temporal sense,  'She has just now understood the passage'.  'Understand' can be punctive (inchoative) as well as durative. // ' ... what you did not understand yet' is set in a past timeframe,  ' ... what you did not understand at that time'. This makes your second sentence infelicitous without unusual context.

Comment: So, it would be better to say 'She has just now understood what you don't understood yet.' ? I can see why it's best to not put 'just' without adding more structure to the sentence, but I'm not sure if I do it well. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your latest variant is a strange-sounding (though grammatical) sentence.  'She has just now understood a point that _you_ don't yet understand' or less formally 'She has just now understood something that _you_ haven't got yet' would be my choices. My first-mentioned choice here is itself a little jarring, using _understand/ood_ in the punctive (realise) as well as the durative sense so close together.

Comment: Oh, ok. It makes more sense to me now ! Thank you for your help, and for your explanations.

Comment: I don't think "understood" is that great of a choice here, at least in the first part of the sentence, for the reasons above.  I vote for: "She just figured out something that you still don't understand."

Answer (score 0):

> 1. She just understood what you haven't understood yet.
> 2. She has just understood what you did not understand yet.
> 3. She just understood what you have yet to understand.

In (3), *have yet to* isn't in the present perfect; rather, it's an idiom in the simple present. [Collins defines](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/have-yet-to-do-something) "to have yet to (do something)" as "to have not yet (done something)," making it equivalent to (1). So we need only consider (1) and (2)

Particularly in American English, the simple past is often acceptable with both *just* and *yet,* though it is much more likely with the former; [my answer to this previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/610578/470858) covers this issue. (1) is perfectly acceptable, but I think that most (including myself) would find (2) rather unnatural, since it uses the simple past with *yet* but the present perfect with *just.*